# undefined labels piechart - chartjs

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

can you help me. i want show my data in percententage value. but my label is undefined. how i show my label to?

[this my chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ML3i7.png)

```
 var options = {
   tooltips: {
     custom: true
   },
   plugins: {
     datalabels: {
       display: true,
       formatter: (value, ctx) => {
         let datasets = ctx.chart.data.datasets;
         if (datasets.indexOf(ctx.dataset) === datasets.length - 1) {
           let sum = datasets[0].data.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
           let percentage = Math.round((value / sum) * 100) + '%';
           return percentage;
         } else {
           return percentage;
         }
       },
       color: '#fff',
     }
   }
 };
 var ctx = document.getElementById("pie-chart").getContext('2d');
 var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
   type: 'pie',
   data: {
     datasets: data
   },
   options: options
 });
```

Comment: this my refrece code [link](https://jsfiddle.net/a1Lvn4eb/55/)

Comment: Your datasets are just data, but where is that data? Is it a const? I feel that your error relies somewhere in that data.

Answer (score 0):

Labels array is not supposed to be in the dataset itself but is supposed to be in the main data object like so:

```js
 var data = [{
   data: [50, 55, 60, 33],
   backgroundColor: [
     "#4b77a9",
     "#5f255f",
     "#d21243",
     "#B27200"
   ],
   borderColor: "#fff"
 }];

 var options = {
   plugins: {
     datalabels: {
       formatter: (value, ctx) => {

         let sum = 0;
         let dataArr = ctx.chart.data.datasets[0].data;
         dataArr.map(data => {
           sum += data;
         });
         let percentage = (value * 100 / sum).toFixed(2) + "%";
         return percentage;


       },
       color: '#fff',
     }
   }
 };


 var ctx = document.getElementById("pie-chart").getContext('2d');
 var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
   type: 'pie',
   data: {
      labels: ["India", "China", "US", "Canada"],
     datasets: data
   },
   options: options
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-datalabels@0.4.0/dist/chartjs-plugin-datalabels.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="pie-chart"></canvas>
```